# How can I access the MediaPlayer functionality from another device?

Tags: apple-music, apple-musickit

I am playing music from the Apple Music app on device A and want to skip the song remotely from device B. My first idea was to save an auth token from device A to a database and call the API from device B through that token.

How can I access the MediaPlayer functionality from another device?

Thanks in advance. Any insight is highly appreciated :slight_smile:

Comment: No idea if that auth token idea will work – my understanding was that it just gave you permission to access the api, and that it wasn't a way of controlling playback on a certain device.


I have actually done this task in another way though. I have the player app which (via the media player framework) plays music either through system Music app or my own app, and then a remote app which can control playback of the player app. I do this by the use of a listener and a Firestore database. It works, but is crude perhaps.

Comment: @JackVanderpump This was actually exactly what I am now trying to do. Thank you so much Jack! I appreciate you taking the time to help me out :)

Comment: No worries, this works fine, and happy to share code, although I'm sure a more sophisticated answer exists!